# why is python not recognizing a text file when I run it from c#?

Tags: python, c#, text-files

the Problematic code:

````
```
def loadNumbers(file="ClientNumbers.txt"):
    numbersFile = open(file)
    numbers = numbersFile.readlines()
    return numbers
```
````

When running this code from my python IDE it works fine.
But when I use system diagnostics from C# to run the python script, I get the error that ClientNumbers.txt is not an existing file or directory.

the C# code:

```
 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Users\francois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = @"..\..\python\sender.py";
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;
        start.LoadUserProfile = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
                Console.WriteLine("success from c#");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine(stderr);
            }
        }
```

is there any reason behind this?

I tried moving the text file around and adjusting the path accordingly, but to no prevail.

The C# application and python script is in different subfolders within one folder.

The loadNumbers method is called and assigned to a variable: number= loadNumbers()

this is where the program stops and gives me the file to not found error

Comment: Your problem is working directory. Add the following: `start.WorkingDirectory = @"..\..\python";`

Comment: Thank you, it works now.